# Gromov-Witten invariants of singular spaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gromov-witten-theory

I wonder if there is any situation where one can talk about Gromov-Witten invariants 
or quantum multiplication for singular varieties. Ideally, I would like have a situation
where for a singular variety $X$ one can define quantum multiplication operators 
by elements of ORDINARY cohomology of $X$ on 
the INTERSECTION cohomology of $X$ (I have some examples where I know what I want the answer
to be, but I don't know how to ask the question).

In fact, I will be ready to start with the following simple example: assume that $X$ just
has quotient singularities, i.e. locally it looks like $Y/G$ where $Y$ is smooth
and $G$ is a finite group. In this case the intersection cohomology coincides with the
ordinary cohomology, so my question is whether in this case one can define quantum
multiplication. One warning: I am talking about quantum cohomology of $X$ itself, not
about what is called "orbifold quantum cohomology" (which in many cases
coincides with the quantum cohomology of a good resolution of $X$).